# Multiple schema.org HowTo instructions on one page

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I have a problem with HowTo objects in schema.org data format (JSON-LD to be precise). I was trying to google something, but HowTo name is rather problematic.

I have two instructions on the same webpage. I'd like to add two [HowTo](https://schema.org/HowTo) objects so that they look pretty in google. I'm using JSON-LD to put the objects on the page. I was trying to simply put two HowTo objects:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@type": "HowTo",
            ...
        },
        {
            "@type": "HowTo",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

but Google's Rich Result Test (https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) says that I can put only one HowTo object on a page. I'm not surprised as that's what the google documentation says: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/how-to#how-to (if the link doesn't lead to the correct section: *Contents -> Structured data type definitions -> HowTo*)

You can check it for yourself and experiment with an example HTML I've made using two examples from google documentation (I'm not putting it directly on Stack as it's a little long): https://gist.github.com/Hoxmot/2eec6a39bcd9fe2b46a8eaadea9afe27

The problem is that it also says that: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/how-to#how-to-section (*Contents -> Structured data type definitions -> HowToSection*)

> For listing multiple ways to complete a task, use multiple HowTo objects.

Is there a way to have two (or more) HowTo instructions on one page? I was also trying to use multiple HowToSections but that doesn't work as desired - it's listed as one solution.

Comment: give each a unique `@id`

Comment: @JayGray thanks for a suggestion. I've added `@id` to both HowTos (`qwe` and `zxc` if it makes a difference). Unfortunately, it didn't work. I've updated the gist so that it contains those ids.

Comment: dang! methinks this is a bug in the google implementation of the schema data model. have tried to do this several ways (`@CreativeWork/hasPart` and `@ItemList/itemListElement`) - all fail. will use this example to get feedback from https://support.google.com/webmasters/threads?hl=en&thread_filter=(category:structured_data). IMHO it should be possible to aggregate an array of `@HowTo`. There is zero documentation stating that this variant (or any variant) of `@CreativeWork` cannot be aggregated.

Comment: @JayGray actually, there is a statement that `HowTo` cannot be aggregated. In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/how-to#how-to) I've linked, under _HowTo_ (the link should direct there; if not, it should be listed in the _Contents_ on the right), there's written: _There must be one `HowTo` type definition per page._ So even though that doesn't make sense to me, it's according to documentation.

Comment: ok, but it `ain't` in the data model. I'll follow up because we shouldn't have to figure this stuff out by an obscure reference in documentation. Thanks for posting this question.

Comment: You can provide feedback in the documentation. I personally think they need to clarify that section implying you can mark up multiple How-tos on a single page.